# Facebook - PopUp Invite Friend in iFrame application

Tags: facebook

I'm developing facebook game, that using `iFrame`.

How to show popUp invite Friend ?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the Javascript API within your iFrame. You can write some FBML to create the friend invitation dialog. See the example here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#requests

If you want a popup you may have to use the `FB.ui` method:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Requests Dialog.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/